# How to handle applying functions to incorrect values?

Tags: haskell

If I had data and I wasn't sure if this was an Integer or a String, but I wanted to apply (+1) to it, if its an integer great, but if its a String- do nothing, how would I handle this? Is this where `Nothing` comes in?

Comment: Naively, the type system doesn't allow you to pass a `String` or an `Integer` in such a way that you don't know which it is. You'll have to give an example of what you mean by "data", like where it is from and how it is represented in your program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, Haskell functions are strongly typed, which means they specify the types of their inputs and outputs.  In order to even accept a value of multiple types in the first place, you need to use `Either` to hold them within the same type.  So, for example, if you want to receive either a `String` or an `Integer`, then your function must have type:

```
f :: Either String Integer -> ...
```

Then, the way you write your function is to pattern match on the `Either` to see which type of value you received.  You would write something like:

```
-- str is a String
f (Left  str) -> ... 
-- int is an Integer
f (Right int) -> ...
```

So, the easiest way to do what you want is to only increment the number if it is an `Integer`, but leave the `String` untouched.  You would write it like this:

```
-- Don't do anything if it is a string
f (Left  str) = Left  str
-- Increment it if it is an integer
f (Right int) = Right (int + 1)
```

If you ask the compiler to infer the type of the above function, you will get:

```
f :: Either String Int -> Either String Int
```

Haskell has a nice trick to avoid the above boilerplate, which is to use `fmap` from the `Functor` class.  This lets us automatically write functions on just the `Right` half of the `Either` while completely ignoring whatever is in the `Left` half, like so:

```
f = fmap (+1)
```

If we infer the type of the above function, it actually comes out to:

```
f :: (Functor f, Num a) => f a -> f a
```

But in our case we can specialize the type by setting `a` to `Integer` and `f` to `Either String`:

```
f :: Either String Int -> Either String Int
```

In other words, `Either String` is one example of an instance of the `Functor` class, of which there are many.

However, note that in order to use this function on integers or strings, you must first wrap them in `Left` or `Right` constructors.  For example, these will not type-check:

```
f 1   -- WRONG!
f "a" -- WRONG!
```

But these will:

```
f (Right  1) -- Correct!
f (Left "a") -- Correct!
```

This means that if you had, say, a list of integers an strings, you would have to write it something like:

```
list = [Right 1, Left "a", Right 2]
```

Notice that if you try to mix integers and strings within a list, you get a type error:

```
list = [1, "a", 2] -- WRONG!
```

Then we could map `f` over the first correct `list` to get:

```
map f list = [Right 2, Left "a", Right 3]
```

Comment: How are you pattern-matching to detect whether the type is string or integer? I didn't get that bit

Comment: @user997112 The function only accepts values that you wrap in a `Left` or `Right` constructor.  This wrapping is not done automatically for you and it is your job to embed the values within these constructors.  I can give a much more detailed answer if you explain where you get your `Integer` or `String` from in the first place.

Comment: I just wondered, is there any way in haskell to tell whether a value was an Integer or a String?

Comment: @user997112 Yes, you just check the output type of the function you are calling.  If the output type of the function is `Integer`, you received an `Integer`.  If the output type of the function is a `String`, you received a `String`.

Answer (score 5):

## We Don't Want to Mix Types Willy-Nilly

You say

> So say I had a list but this list could be ["a"] or it could be [1], if i wanted to apply some functions without knowing the exact type within the list,

Haskell doesn't let you make such a list - all the elements in a list have to have the same type. You could have `[1,2,3]` or `["a","cheese","4"]`, but not `["a",1]`. Haskell will make sure only apply functions that work with the elements in the list. Both Haskell and you will always be able to work out the type of the elements in your list. This type knowledge is called static typing, and at first it seems needlessly rigid, but it's actually very flexible indeed. The golden rule is: the compiler knows what data you have, all the time.

> how could I handle type problems?

**You won't get type problems like this!** That's the joy of static typing - programs that make mistakes with the types of data or with converting between types of data *don't compile* - you'll find the mistake before your code even runs!

Maybe you have a stream of data that might mix strings and numbers. The *first* question you need to ask is "what do I want to do with them, and do I *really* need to mix them together?". Is there a better way of seperating them out? For example, in Haskell it's really easy to write fully featured staticly-typed parsers (look up parsec if this is what you need).

---

## New: Ignoring non-integers

(On re-reading your question title, perhaps this is what you're after.)

It's quite easy to ignore non-integers. Like you mention, you could use `Nothing` and its counterpart `Just`, like this

```
myData = ["nan","45","3454.5","that's not an int, it's a float!","4","6"]

maybeInts :: [String] -> [Maybe Integer] -- type signature needed so Haskell knows you want Integers
maybeInts = map maybeRead
```

which uses a handy function `maybeRead` to convert each value, but you'd need to either `import Network.CGI.Protocol (maybeRead)` or since that has no right not to be in `Data.Maybe`, copy-and-paste the code instead:

```
maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
maybeRead = fmap fst . listToMaybe . reads 
  -- take all parses, grab the first one, ignore the remaining text
```

The value you'll get for `maybeInts myData` will be

```
[Nothing, Just 45, Nothing, Nothing, Just 4, Just 6]
```

but perhaps you didn't want all that `Nothing`/`Just` fluff, and would rather just get the Integers.
If you [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5bMaybe+a%5d+-%3E+%5ba%5d) for `[Maybe a] -> [a]` you'll find `catMaybes` from the `Data.Maybe` module, so let's `import Data.Maybe` then define

```
intsOnly :: [String] -> [Int]
intsOnly = catMaybes.map maybeRead  -- read them, ignore Nothings and unwrap Justs
```

So when you do `intsOnly myData` you get

```
[45,4,6]
```

and then if you want to add one to them all, you can do

```
map (+1) (intsOnly myData)
```

which is

```
[46,5,7]
```

as required.

## Mixing Types in an Orderly Fashion

If you have to mix Integers and Strings, you can do

```
[Left 5, Right "a", Right "hello", Left 6]
```

which is a list of either `Int`egers or `String`s, so of type `Either Int String`, but perhaps you want to mix more than just numbers and text, perhaps you'd like an integer, a string, a time or a list of strings. You can roll your own then:

```
data MyStuff = MyInt Int | MyString String | MyDate DateTime | MyList FilePath [String] 
  deriving Show
```

which can be in a list like

```
mystuff = [MyInt 6,  MyString "Hello",  MyString "MyString isn't a great name", 
    MyList "C:/temp/stuff.txt" ["yeah","give","them","problem-specific", "names"], 
    MyInt 12,  MyString "instead"]
```

(Notice Haskell is case-sensitive; `MyStuff` is a type, `MyString` is a type constructor (a sort of function wrapping data into a type) and `mystuff` is a variable. All variables are constant!)

How would your data end up wrapped like that in the `My___` tags? Well maybe it started as a whole load of text in a file or from a network connection or something, and your parser split it into ints, strings, dates and lists of strings, tagging them as it went along (very easy to do).

...and you can seperate between them by writing a function that is defined differently according to which data it gets:

```
report :: MyStuff -> IO ()
report (MyInt n) = mapM_ print [1..n]   -- turn the numbers 1..n into print commands, then combine them
report (MyString xs) = print xs         -- just print the string.
report (MyList filename contents) 
    = writeFile filename (unlines contents) -- write them on seperate lines in the file
report _ = return ()                    -- if it's anything else, ignore it and do nothing.
```

Now if you felt like it, you could do

```
mapM_ report mylist
```

and it would print some numbers, a couple of strings, save a file, print some more numbers and finally print a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a value that could be one of two types, you can use the `Either` type for that value. `Either` takes two other types as parameters so `Either a b` is  value that is either of type `a` or of type `b`. The two cases are identified by two different constructors `Left` and `Right` meaning either the left (`a`) or right (`b`) type of the either. In your case you would use `Either String Integer`. To manipulate the values you can use pattern matching. For example,

```
foo :: Either String Int -> Either String Int
foo (Left s) = Left s
foo (Right n) = Right (n+1)
```

implements the transformation you ask about in the question.